# Access forbidden while trying to get list of YouTube Members

Tags: php, youtube-data-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to retrieve a list of channel members using the YouTube API in PHP.
I have all the necessary credentials, such as the client ID and API key, and I am able to authenticate successfully.
I have also been granted the following scopes:
"`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.channel-memberships.creator`"
"`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly`"

Here is the code I'm using:

```php
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAccessToken($access_token);
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
$members = $youtube->members->listMembers('snippet');
```

However, when I run this PHP code, I receive an error code 403, with following error message:
"Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized."

I have double-checked that I have all the necessary credentials and scopes, and that the authentication is successful.

The application I'm building will be used exclusively by me.
The YouTube channel I'm trying to retrieve the members list from, is mine.

Can anyone offer any insight into why I might be receiving this error message, and how I can fix it?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

---

**Edit:**

After a lot of research, I noticed this paragraph in this page:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/members/list

> Note: This endpoint can only be used by individual creators to make
> requests for their own, channel-memberships-enabled YouTube channel.
> Reach out to your Google or YouTube representative to request access.

So, my question now is:
How do I reach out to a Google or YouTube representative to request access?

Answer (score 0):

@ilias_gr

Try following PHP Code reference.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAccessToken($access_token);

// Create a YouTube service instance
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

// Define the request parameters
$params = array(
  'part' => 'snippet',
  'filter' => 'subscriber', // optional: specify 'subscriber' or 'owner' to filter by membership type
  'maxResults' => 50, // optional: specify the maximum number of results per page
  'channelId' => 'YOUR_CHANNEL_ID', // replace with your actual channel ID
);

// Make the API request
$response = $youtube->members->listMembers($params);

// Extract the list of members from the response
$members = $response->getItems();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this link is not related to the YouTube API.

Comment: This is how I have done it, but I get the message "`Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized.`". 
Also, your code is not 100% correct. The `$params` array has incorrect parameters. `filter` and `channelId` parameters do not exist. 
For more info on how to set the parameters correctly, please refer to the file `Members.php` in this path: `vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/YouTube/Resource/`